# How to use opencv screen recording output for movement detection in python?

Tags: python, opencv

As a security guard we have to look an eye on a 60 inches TV which provides 20 camera output on it. So its really hard to watch the pot always. I decide to develope a programm to rectanglar the movement object in screen and make some beeps. My first step is to capture the screen frames. With below code its possible.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss
from PIL import Image

bounding_box = {'top': 100, 'left': 0, 'width': 400, 'height': 300}

sct = mss()

while True:
    sct_img = sct.grab(bounding_box)
    cv2.imshow('screen', np.array(sct_img))

    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

As i understand we can use opencv to do some magic. There are some nice tutorial on net like [this one](http://www.robindavid.fr/opencv-tutorial/motion-detection-with-opencv.html). My problem is they got frames or stream from cams or ofline video files but here i have screen recording. Can you guys help me how to forward these frames into motion detection algorithm? Thanks

Comment: that blog post is using an API I've never seen. it's probably VERY outdated.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yeah, looks like the last version of OpenCV that API was in is 2.2 , released in 2010. The github repo of that "nice tutorial" is from 2012 and was barely touched since.

Answer (score 1):

The process is the same, you have to modify the image source.
In the example you linked - in the 'The smart way' code - replace

`cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)`
with
`sct.grab(bounding_box)`

to use the screengrab as image source

Comment: Thanks but as I understand it just get one image from screen.